# seaborn pairplot seperate bins in diagonal

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
sns.pairplot(iris, hue='class', palette='husl',kind='reg')
plt.show()
```

That is the code I used to generate the plot(picture below).
There is also a picture of how I want it to look.

This is how it looks now:
[image: this is how it looks now]

This is how I want it to look:
[image: this is how I want it to look]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that compared to the example you show on the bottom, you use a different palette and a regression line.

Once you leave out `palette='husl',kind='reg'` you get the plot on the bottom.

The remaining difference is due to a different style in different matplotlib versions. The picture on the bottom has been produced with a version of matplotlib prior to version 2. To get the old style back in matplotlib 2 you can use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('classic')
```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('classic')
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.pairplot(iris, hue="species")

plt.show()
```

produces [image]

Comment: What do you mean by "it"? What is unrelated to what?

Comment: Using the classic style fixed the spacing issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import seaborn as sns; 
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
sns.pairplot(iris, hue='class')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.